# Exponential equation with square variable as an exponent?

Tags: diophantine-equations, exponentiation

I am trying to solve the following exponential equation where the variable is squared. Most likely it is not difficult, but I am just missing the technique: what is the way to solve an exponential equation when the variable is a square? Thanks.

$$
2^x{^{^2}}+2^1{^{-x{^2}}} = 3
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Your equation is:
$$
2^{x^2}+\frac{2}{2^{x^2}}=3
$$
for: $y=2^{x^2}$ becomes
$$y+\frac{2}{y}=3$$
that you can solve for $y$.